# How to use CKEditor 5 CodeSnippet plugin in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

How can install code snippet plugin in CKEditor 5 vue.js I had google searched on it, but didn't get luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the one you are looking for:

https://github.com/Suraj151/ckeditor5-code-block

You need to install the classic editor first

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

There is a code plugin as well in basic style plugin.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/basic-styles.html

To install:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles
```